# Ajax cross domain POST in IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I am trying to make a ajax cross domain POST in IE9 and IE8 to a rest endpoint that resets a password and am not having any luck. The ajax call I am trying to make is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: postUrl,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data:{ "userid":uid, "email":email, "password":password },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (status){
        console.log(status);
    }
});
```

I am also making sure to include the following before the POST call:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

Everytime I make the call it goes into the error function. It says the status is success however when I try to login with the new password it is not working which means it wasnt a success. The following is the response that I output to the log:

```
[object Object]{readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}
```

Also note that I am calling the `jQuery.XDomainRequest.js` by MoonScript. That several other stack overflow answers say to do. And my jquery version is 1.11.3

Can someone please provide me some direction on this.

Comment: Is it working e.g on chrome?

Comment: @A.Wolff In all other browsers I make a $.post call. However I need to still support IE8 and IE9 which don't recoginze the $.post so this ajax call I am only making when the browser is ie8 and ie9. The $.post call does work in chrome though